# Boost mpl list and auto_test_case_template compilation error

Tags: c++, boost

I have been battling the compiler for sometime now. Here is my code:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>

namespace MyMessageNamespace
{
    class ParticularMessage
    {
        template <int N>
        void SetSomething(int myValue) {};
    };
}

template <typename MyMessageT>
struct MyMessage
{
    using MyMessageType = MyMessageT;
};

using MyMessages = boost::mpl::list<MyMessage<MyMessageNamespace::ParticularMessage>>;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(MyTestCase, MyMessage, MyMessages)
{
    typename MyMessage::MyMessageType message;
    message.SetSomething<1>(20);
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called: `message.SetSomething<1>(20);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems (you'll kick yourself for the second one).

First, `SetSomething` is a dependent template type. Use the `template` keyword to correct this:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(MyTestCase, MyMessage, MyMessages)
{
    typename MyMessage::MyMessageType message;
    message.template SetSomething<1>(20);
}
```

Second, this reveals that `SetSomething` is inaccessible because it's private. One way to fix this would be to make the member `public:`

```
class ParticularMessage
{
public:
    template <int N>
    void SetSomething(int myValue) {};
};
```

For reference, this now compiles for me (apple clang 7.3.0)

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>

namespace MyMessageNamespace
{
    class ParticularMessage
    {
    public:
        template <int N>
        void SetSomething(int myValue) {};
    };
}

template <typename MyMessageT>
struct MyMessage
{
    using MyMessageType = MyMessageT;
};

using MyMessages = boost::mpl::list<MyMessage<MyMessageNamespace::ParticularMessage>>;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(MyTestCase, MyMessage, MyMessages)
{
    typename MyMessage::MyMessageType message;
    message.template SetSomething<1>(20);
}
```

Compiled with `-std=c++14`

Comment: I now get this error
error: no matching member function for call to 'SetSomething'

Comment: @JonathonHill and you made SetSomething public?

Comment: @JonathonHill i'll add the complete corrected program to the answer

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in mine that wasn't obvious. I fixed up on here but not on my copy